# How to properly fetch a huge ResultSet using JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, swing, resultset, swingworker

I'm facing problems when fetching and processing a huge `ResultSet` from a database using JDBC (a few million rows), in this case MySQL's Connector/J. One of those problems is that even though I'm using a `SwingWorker` and taking measures not to perform any long processing on the Event Dispatch thread, the UI still freezes occasionally. This only happens with huge queries; the approach I'm using works for small ones.

Is there something that can be done to remedy this? Am I improperly handling such large `ResultSet`?

Note: I'm using the [Employees sample database](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/employee/en/employees-installation.html), more specifically the `Salaries` table.

**Sample code**

```
public class TestFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employees";
    static final String USERNAME = "root";
    static final String PASSWORD = "";
    private Connection conn;

    public TestFrame() {
        initComponents();
        initConnection();
    }

    public void initConnection() {
        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
            System.out.println("Connected.");

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")                         
    private void initComponents() {
        java.awt.GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraints;

        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        uiTable = new javax.swing.JTable();
        btnRun = new javax.swing.JButton();
        txtQuery = new javax.swing.JTextField();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new java.awt.GridBagLayout());
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(uiTable);

        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 1;
        gridBagConstraints.fill = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gridBagConstraints.ipadx = 643;
        gridBagConstraints.ipady = 374;
        gridBagConstraints.anchor = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        gridBagConstraints.weightx = 1.0;
        gridBagConstraints.weighty = 1.0;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new java.awt.Insets(6, 10, 0, 10);
        getContentPane().add(jScrollPane1, gridBagConstraints);

        btnRun.setText("Run");
        btnRun.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnRunActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 2;
        gridBagConstraints.anchor = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new java.awt.Insets(6, 625, 11, 10);
        getContentPane().add(btnRun, gridBagConstraints);

        txtQuery.setText("SELECT * FROM Salaries");
        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.ipadx = 660;
        gridBagConstraints.anchor = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new java.awt.Insets(11, 10, 0, 10);
        getContentPane().add(txtQuery, gridBagConstraints);

        pack();
    }                       

    private void btnRunActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        String query = txtQuery.getText();
        SwingWorker<DefaultTableModel, Object> worker = new SwingWorker<DefaultTableModel, Object>() {

            @Override
            protected DefaultTableModel doInBackground() {
                DefaultTableModel tableModel = null;
                try (Statement stmt = conn.createStatement()) {
                    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
                    ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
                    String[] columnNames = new String[rsmd.getColumnCount()];
                    for (int i = 1; i <= columnNames.length; i++) {
                        columnNames[i - 1] = rsmd.getColumnName(i);
                    }

                    tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, 0);
                    while (rs.next()) {
                        Vector row = new Vector();
                        for (int i = 1; i <= columnNames.length; i++) {
                            row.add(rs.getString(i));
                        }
                        tableModel.addRow(row);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return tableModel;
            }

            @Override
            protected void done() {
                try {
                    DefaultTableModel tableModel;
                    if ((tableModel = get()) != null) {
                        uiTable.setModel(tableModel);
                    }                    
                } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException ex) {
                }
            }
        };
        worker.execute();
    }                                      

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        }

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            new TestFrame().setVisible(true);
        });
    }

    private javax.swing.JButton btnRun;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtQuery;
    private javax.swing.JTable uiTable;                
}
```

It's also worth mentioning that the UI freezes even before I start to populate the table model.

Comment: A million rows in a JTable? What could a user possibly do with a million rows in a table?

Comment: Copy them, export them to Excel, read them one by one. Anything. But that's out of the scope of this question. It's one of the requirements.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is, the program needs to be able to work through any `ResultSet` seamlessly, no matter how large it is. What the user does is up to them.

Comment: Part of the problem, might be how objects are been created and managed, as the size of the containing object (in this case `DefaultTableModel`) grows in size, it requires more memory, this "could" be placing a strain on the system as it tries to keep up. Also, in your `done` method, the API requires time to process the changes been applied, which can cause a slow down in the UI as it goes through the process of making determinations required to display the data

Comment: @MadProgrammer The freezing occurs even before the `done` method is executed. In fact, the freezing happens while still inside `doInBackground`, which seems odd considering we aren't in Event dispatch thread. Could this be a Java thing that can't be remedied?

Comment: @Morgan I'd be looking at the GC overhead and memory application profiles - through a profiler, it might provide some additional information about what's going

Comment: @MadProgrammer I will be honest, I never profiled an application like this. Would something along the likes of Java Mission Control work or do I need something else?

Comment: @Morgan Possibly, but I just the profiler built into the IDE :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer Oh, right. I completely overlooked NetBeans having one. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you shouldn't read the million records. Doesn't matter how you read the result set, if you read one million things it takes time... And if you put all the records in memory it takes a bunch of memory too.

The usual way to do that is reading some records, let's say ¿200?, presenting the 200 records and adding buttons to go forward and read another 200, and backward, to read the previous 200 records, so the user can navigate through the data without moving one million records between the server and yout client.

Just need to add some conditions in your query `WHERE` clausule and keep record of the last read record, so when you make a query you start the cursor from the last record:

```
select * from *** 
where ****
AND ID > 'myStoredLastReadID'
```

Or something like that. Then, change the `while ( rs.next())` for a

```
int ix = 0;
while ( rs.next() && (ix++) < 200 ) {
```

And add the buttons to your GUI. You will need something more, for example to go backward, but I think you can catch the idea.

If you really need to show one million records to your user... well, it will be slow whatever you do  because you are going to move one million things from the server to your client, store one million things in memory, calculate which part of that million things the GUI must paint in the screen...

Comment: I have no control over the amount of records. The queries are dynamic. The user is free to type ANY query and if it returns a million rows the application needs to adapt. To give you an example, this is similar to other DB management apps such as SQL Server Management studio, Navicat, or PHPMyAdmin. I suppose I could detect when the number of rows is getting high, but I have no way of knowing beforehand what query the user will execute.

Comment: Also, the UI freezing not only happens as I'm populating the `DefaultTableModel`, it also happens when I execute the query against the DB engine, that is, before the `ResultSet` even arrives.

Comment: well, if you don't know the query in advance it's difficult to choose the field for the `and field > 'last'`... Whaever, if I were you I'd limit the number of read records. I've used SQL tools that put a limit to the number of records to read in the configuration dialog. Just for testing, you could change the SwingWorker for a regular Thread to isolate the reading loop from Swing, but I keep thinking that the problem is in resources, like CPU or memory, that put stress in the JVM.

Comment: SwingWorker is a thread. A thread that uses Swing stuff but a thread in the end. So instead using a SwingWorker use a Thread. Create a new class that extends Thread (or implements Runnable) that access the database, so you will have a class with the Swing stuff and a completly separate class with the database stuff, working in a separate thread.

Comment: Then in the button eventhandler create the DB object, start the thread, join the thread, get the model and assign the model to the table. That way you will be completly sure that the recordset reading will not use Swing at all. If the UI keeps freezing then you will know that is because swing and your database loop share the CPU and the memory, not because you are breaking something in the Swing internals. And it's "theoricaly" correct to sperate those things,

Comment: But I keep thinking that the best is to limitate the number of records to read adding a limit in the `while` condition, because to do it really well, the button event handler should start the thread, show a dialog with something with eye candy and exit to avoid freeze the UI in the button event handler method, and when the DB thread ends, that you could know using some kind of listener, then update the table model. Not easy.

Comment: Where in that new thread would I assign the table model with the fetched data? Would I have to use `EventQueue.invokeLater`?

Comment: I tried your suggestion of using a non-SwingWorker thread but the UI still occasionally hangs the moment I execute the query.

Comment: I've been doing a demo of a button that calls a thread, so I'm going to add a new response to put code (perhaps it can be done here, but I'm new in Stackoverflow and I don't know how...)

Answer (score 0):

Use an `AbstractTableModel` on your own page caching, and just keep reading some pages when not in the cache. Keep the cache limited.

With COUNT(*). and LIMIT you can fetch the pages you are displaying, a kind of caching. This becomes even a bit harder with a faster paging technique, using index fields: say the ID. Then on a sorted table one could page by storing page border IDs.

You probably need to keep the connection open, reopen it on failure. Make a page cache.

Also create a Vector with an initial capacity of the correct size.

```
new Vector(columnNames.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an (quick and very dirty) example of how to call something slow from a button without freezing the main Swing thread.

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


public class TestUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
  JButton but;

  public TestUI() {
    super( "Test...");

    but = new JButton( "Test");
    but.setActionCommand( "BUTTON");
    but.addActionListener( this);

    getContentPane().add( but, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    pack();
    setVisible( true);
  }

  public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent ev) {
    if ( ev.getActionCommand().equals( "BUTTON") ) {
      SlowClass sc = new SlowClass( TestUI.this);
      sc.start();
      /** THIS FREEEZES
      try {
        sc.join();
      }
      catch ( InterruptedException e) {
      }
      */
    }
    else if ( ev.getActionCommand().equals( "QUERY_END") ) {
      System.out.println( "END");
      but.setText( "Query over");
    }
  }

  public class SlowClass extends Thread {
    ActionListener listener;

    SlowClass( ActionListener listener) {
      this.listener = listener;
    }

    public void run() {
      try {
        Thread.sleep( 10000);

        listener.actionPerformed( new ActionEvent( this, 0, "QUERY_END"));
      }
      catch ( Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }

  public static void main( String args[]) throws Exception {
    TestUI tui = new TestUI();
  }
}
```

Create a new thread, start the thread from the event hadler and, using a listener, wait to be notified when the work is done. If you wait in the same invocation, in the commented lines, the main Swing thread freezes waiting for the end, so the listener is important.

This example starts a thread that doesn't consume CPU, so it works because nobady is fighting for the machine resources, you can resize the freame while the thread is working because Swing is free to work. But this is not your case, you are doing a lot of things, so we don't know if Swing hangs because there's something wrong in the code or because there isn't enough CPU and memory for Swing and the query.

Try something like this (cleaner, please, handling the listener correctly, not adding it in the constructor...) to see what happens. Or change the superquery for a sleep(20000) in your code to see if it hangs to get a hint of what happens.